# Route traffic to another instance using elb on the basis of Authorization token in header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I want to route requests to different EC2 instances on the basis of Authorization token in headers.

The AWS doc says that it can route on the basis of the Host name in the header or the path based routing. Is there any other way I can use the elb to route requests.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to use other (non-hostname)  headers as a means to target requests. You could consider an nginx redirect or rewrite that would map the header to a specific hostname or path, and use existing targeting methods.

Comment: Just to be clear, the aws-elb will redirect request to nginx and then `nginx` will rewrite the request (maybe a change in hostname) that will be sent to the AWS-ELB and it will be forwarded to different instances on the basis of hostname. Right?
I have never used nginx, so pardon if the comment is not meaningful or way too abstract. I want to confimr this possibility. 
Found this reference, https://serverfault.com/a/660142
And thanks for the response.

Comment: You bet. I can give you a more complete example. Can you give me an example of the header you are referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the Authorization request header where the type used is bearer token. 
The value for the header is a string and that is unique for all the users. On the basis of this string/token, I want to route the requests.

Comment: Any Updates on this?